# How do I join my Raspbian server to a VLan

Tags: networking, raspbian

Just so I don't waste anyone's time, I am not looking to join two networks on one network adapter or route between wifi and Ethernet.

I have a Netgear managed switch. My Raspberry Pi is attached to a port that is tagged with Vlan 10. I just want to provide a static IP address and have the server take part in Vlan10. I have a Unifi Security gateway that takes care of all the routing between the different Vlans.

I have had this working using ubuntu 18.04 using netplan. without trying to confuse you, this is my netplan config, which I am trying to duplicate using Raspbian.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  bridges:
    br10:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan10 ]
      addresses: [ 192.168.10.20/24 ]
      gateway4: 192.168.10.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - "192.168.10.3"
          - "8.8.8.8"
  vlans:
    vlan10:
      id: 10
      link: eth0
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> this is my netplan config, which I am trying to duplicate using Raspbian.

You cannot just duplicate it to the [Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-os/) because RaspiOS does not use netplan. So lets look how to configure the RasPi to achieve what you want.

As far as I understand you want to connect the RasPi to VLAN10 with a static ip address. From the netplan settings I can see that packages to the RasPi are tagged with the VLAN id so it has to manage it by itself. Of course this is possible but to keep things simple I suggest to let your managed switch doing this work.

On the managed switch set the port to the RasPi to an **Untagged port** but set its **PVID** (Port VLAN ID) to 10. This way the RasPi will see the network packages untagged and you can configure it as usual.  The switch will add (and remove) the VLAN tag with PVID 10 so the RasPi will become a member of VLAN10.

How to give the RasPi a static ip address you can look at [Raspberry Pi - TCP/IP networking](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/tcpip/).